# Append UI element ionic

Tags: angular, user-interface, ionic-framework, append, element

i have a problem, i wan't to create and append a new ionic element into my document while the app are runing and without changing the current page.
[i made a illustration to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13f1m.png)
I use the latest version of ionic (3.19.0)

## add.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="add"></ion-icon>
</ion-content>
```

## add.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add',
  templateUrl: 'add.html',
})
export class AddPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
}
```

Comment: so what problem you are facing ?

Comment: I can't find a solution on internet

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found a solution.
You just need to make a for-binded loop on html element:

### Example:

### add.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let i of inputs">
  <ion-label floating>Data</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="add()"></ion-icon>
```

### add.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add',
  templateUrl: 'add.html',
})
export class AddPage {
  items = new Array(1);
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}
  add() {
    this.items.length += 1;
  }
}
```

You simply need to set the length of the list to add a UI element to the  document